# How to resolve Node js unicode conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, wireshark

I am working on a UDP based client application. I have been facing the issue of Unicode(UTF - 8)
conversation. I did convert decimal to Utf - 8 it was not given proper output. I got output like(À).
if I send this output through UDP Client. The output is changed by(Ã). Why it was happing. Even those
hex values also changed by C0 to C3.could anyone has to answer me? how to send Unicode in UDP
communication?

```
 const dgram = require('dgram');
 const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
 const HOST = '192.168.43.232';
 const PORT = 5000;

 const message = String.fromCharCode(192);
 console.log(message); //<À>


client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('UDP message sent to ' + message + ' ' + HOST + ':' + PORT); //UDP message sent to À 
    192.168.43.232:5000
    client.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is working as expected. According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_send_msg_offset_length_port_address_callback), if the first argument to `socket.send()` is a string, it is automatically converted to UTF-8 buffer. The character 192 (U+00C0) is correctly converted to UTF-8 bytes `0xC380`. The point you are missing here is that UTF-8 is not a single byte encoding; UTF-8 is a **variable width** character encoding. For all code points greater than 127, UTF-8 takes more than one byte. Therefore, in this case, the problem is with your client which is only considering the first byte of received message. You can see the UTF-8 [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for more information.

Comment: Even if send like this also same problem  for example ("\u00C0") changed to("\u00C3")  and in Wireshark alse i got output ("C3").i am expecting output is (C0) var ne_buffer= ["\u00C0"]   client.send(ne_buffer,PORT, HOST, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('UDP message sent to ' + ne_buffer + ' ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);

        
       
        client.close();
    });

Comment: U+00C0 === \u00C0 === (0xC380 in UTF-8). The code point takes 2 bytes when encoded as UTF-8. On your UDP receiver, you need to take the received buffer and decode it as a UTF-8 string.

Comment: I'm certainly not a node.js expert by any means, but maybe something like this helps? 

    message = Buffer.from('c0', 'hex'); 
    client.send(message, 0, 1, PORT, HOST, (err) ...